# ubuntu 14.04 with froxlor running on php-fpm using letsencrypt wont work with global acme location config

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, nginx, fastcgi, letsencrypt

Here is my problem. To use letsencrypt acme on every domain I add `include /etc/nginx/acme.conf` in every vhost config:

acme.conf

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    alias /var/www/froxlor/.well-known/acme-challenge;

    allow all

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/(.*) {
        default_type text/plain;
    }
}
```

vhost.conf

```
server {
    listen <IP>:80;
    server_name example.de;
    include /etc/nginx/acme.conf;

    root /var/customers/webs/example/example.de/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
    }


    location @rewrites {
        rewrite ^ /index.php last;
    }

    location /webalizer {
        alias /var/customers/webs/example/webalizer/example.de/;
        auth_basic "Restricted Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/froxlor-htpasswd/1-229049931c767630a601718d62346214.htpasswd;
    }

    location ~ ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
        try_files /ec157a05122f20edd82ad600247730bf.htm @php;
    }

    location @php {
        try_files $1 = 404;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)\$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$1;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $2;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/example-example.de-php-fpm.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }


}
```

I put a `test.html` in `.well-known/acme-challenge` so that `example.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.html` should return that file but instead I get a redirect to `example.de/well-known/acme-challenge/test.html/`.

Things I tried in acme.conf:

1. changing location to `^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge` - same effect
2. changing location to `^~ /\.well-known/acme-challenge` - same effect
3. use `root /var/froxlor` instead of `alias` - same effect

I think I got lost somewhere in nginx location resolving order, which I tried to fix with:

1. in case of resolving order
2. in case of regex
3. in case of idk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service php5-fpm wasnt running with the new config despite the fact that i `service php5-fpm restart`ed it. 
killing *php5-fpm* it via `kill` and `service php5-fpm start` solved it.